# How to emulate the behaviour of stock.picking.type kanban view?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

> **THE PURPOSE**

I'm trying to develop a menuitem similar to the one you probably use to work with (if you have `stock` module installed). If you go to *Warehouse > Operations > All Operations*, you will see a beautiful kanban view of `stock.picking.type` model with the available picking types. If you click on the *All operations* link of any of the picking type boxes, you will be redirected to `stock.picking` tree view. Well, that's the only thing I need, but, I want the link to redirect you to my custom `stock.move` tree instead.

So, I've created my menuitem, and my own `stock.picking.type` kanban view which is going to redirect to my custom `stock.move` tree view.

> **MY CODE**

**My Kanban view**

```
<record id="stock_picking_type_2_move_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.picking.type.2.move.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking.type</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban class="oe_background_grey" create="0">
            <field name="complete_name"/>
            <field name="color"/>
            <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_color_#{kanban_getcolor(record.color.raw_value)} oe_kanban_card oe_kanban_stock_picking_type">
                        <div class="oe_kanban_content">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><strong><field name="complete_name"/></strong></h4>
                            <div class="oe_items_list oe_kanban_ellipsis">
                                <div>
                                    <a name="%(action_in_alt_move_views)d" type="action">Open moves</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>
```

**My action which opens my kanban (and the default form of `stock.picking.type`)**

```
<record id="action_in_alt_picking_type_views" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Picking types</field>
    <field name="res_model">stock.picking.type</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="stock.view_pickingtype_filter"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to create a new picking type. 
        </p><p>
        The picking type system allows you to assign each stock
        operation a specific type which will alter its views accordingly.  
        On the picking type you could e.g. specify if packing is needed by default, 
        if it should show the customer.  
        </p>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="action_in_alt_picking_type_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="poc_alternative_stock.stock_picking_type_2_move_kanban"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_in_alt_picking_type_views"/>
</record>

<record id="action_in_alt_picking_type_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="stock.view_picking_type_form"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_in_alt_picking_type_views"/>
</record>
```

**My menuitem**

```
<menuitem action="action_in_alt_picking_type_views"
    id="menu_action_in_alt_move_views"
    parent="stock.menu_stock_warehouse_mgmt" sequence="4"/>
```

> **THE BEHAVIOUR**

When I clicked on my menuitem, I got different errors, most of them telling me that the field whatever didn't exist. The problem is that all these fields belonged to a search view I made for `stock.move` model. And I don't know why this search view is being loaded in my `stock.picking.type` action, so Odoo is trying to show my kanban view with a search view of `stock.move`. That's the reason of the errors. If I comment every field of the search view, I get this error:

```
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'state' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('state', '=', 'draft') on stock_picking_type (ctx: )>"
```

Which is the domain of the first filter of my `stock.move` search view.

Why is Odoo trying to load that search view? (If you see my action code, I've even included the parameter `search_view_id`, to try to load the default search view of `stock.picking.type` instead of the `stock.move` one).

And there's a more surprisingly thing and is that if I modify the priority of my `stock.picking.type` kanban view and write 16 for example, it's going to have more priority than the original one (declared in `stock` model), so now if click again on *Warehouse > Operations > All Operations*, my kanban view is loaded. But, hey, here's loaded rightly, and it works perfect, exactly as I want, the kanban view is OK, its search view too, and the link redirects to the `stock.move` view I want...

Can anyone explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code you don't have any domain `('state', '=', 'draft')` i'm assuming when you lunch your code the first time in your action code there was one. and when you had the error you removed it. and in XML removing code will not update the data in database.

```
  <!-- you must tell Odoo empty the field first and next time 
       remove the code(in production) when odoo load some thing to database
       like context, domain, any other value clear it first then remove
       the code -->
  <fied name="domain">[] </field>
```

When you have an error in xml try to remember what code you removed before you clear it from database first.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Cherif. Unfortunately, that solution is not working. I've never created a domain for `action_in_alt_picking_type_views`, it's trying to load the search view of `stock.move` in the action which redirects to `stock.picking.type` model, so Odoo complains for each field. If I remove the filter with the domain `[('state', '=', 'draft')]` from `stock.move` search view, the error is the domain of another filter or even a field of `stock.move` search view too.